# How to write an R function replace a TRUE with "X" and a FALSE with "Y"

Tags: r, function, if-statement, boolean, character

I am currently trying to write a function that assesses if the character variable has an "F" or an "M" inside the character that has multiple numbers as well (ie. 3849F is ID 3849, Female). I have sorted out a function to give me a boolean output that gives TRUE is F is present and FALSE is M is present.

How can I now use this boolean output to replace these with the desired "F" and "M" character values?

The code I have thus far is below:

```
sex = list()    
for (i in 1:length(dataset)){
      fsex = grepl("F", dataset, fixed = T)
      if (fsex == T) sex = c(sex, "F")
      else if (fsex == F) sex = c(sex, "M")
    }
```

[image: the original dataset]

[image: what I would like the output to look like]

[image: fsex output- I desire each TRUE to be replaced with "F" and each FALSE to be replaced with "M"]

Comment: First, `grepl` is vectorized, so no need for a loop. The result of `grepl` is a logical vector. This may be coerced to numeric indices, which can be used to index a vector of "F" and "M":  `x = c("12F", "23M", "34F", "45M")`; `c("M", "F")[grepl("F", x) + 1]`. Please make sure to post a _minimal_ example (easily copy-paste-able, i.e. _not_ an image ;), which potential helpers can try out their code on. Cheers

Comment: @Henrik thank you! This helped and I was able to make it work. Also thank you for the advice on the code examples- I'll make sure to do a pasted version as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Henrik provided what I believe is the answer you're looking for in the comments, but depending on your experience with R it may not be clear.

To elaborate:

```
sex <- c("125F", "X28345M", "2M3")
sex
#>[1] "125F"    "X28345M" "2M3"

output <- ifelse(grepl(sex, pattern = "F", ignore.case = TRUE), "F", "M")
output
#>[1] "F" "M" "M"

fsex <- grepl(sex, pattern = "F", ignore.case = TRUE)
#>[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

You can also replace "F" and "M" with "Female" or "Male", or "0" and "1" easily using this approach.

Comment: Wow thank you! This did help clarify- and worked great.

Answer (score 4):

This works for an arbitrary boolean vector. You can use the dataframe column instead.

```
> bools <- c(T,T,F)
> new_col <- ifelse(bools, "F", "M")
> new_col
[1] "F" "F" "M"
```

You can also reassign the original data.

```
> gender <- c(T,T,F)
> gender <- ifelse(gender, "F", "M")
> gender
[1] "F" "F" "M"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `dplyr` you could achieve this with a single function rather than requiring the function you've already created and then a second function you refer to in the question.

```r
df<- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                ID = c("125F", "13000M", "13120M", "12260M", "21525F")
)

library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
df %>% 
  mutate(fsex = case_when(
    grepl("F", ID) ~ "F",
    grepl("M", ID) ~ "M"
  ))
#>       ID fsex
#> 1   125F      F
#> 2 13000M      M
#> 3 13120M      M
#> 4 12260M      M
#> 5 21525F      F
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Because your data already contains the `F` or `M` value you wish to obtain and it is always at the end of each entry, you might consider using a [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) pattern to extract the last character of each entry as opposed to converting to logical (i.e., your function) and then back to character (i.e., the function you are asking for). The `stringr` package is helpful for this.

Here is an example using the tidyverse:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

dataset <- data.frame(matrix(paste0(sample(1:100), sample(c("M", "F"))), nrow = 10))
dataset
#>     X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7   X8  X9 X10
#> 1  74M 59M 69M 96M 66M 53M  4M  43M 30M 33M
#> 2  64F 25F 95F 71F 16F 14F 22F  70F 20F 48F
#> 3  29M 78M 26M 94M  1M 21M 62M  77M 56M 13M
#> 4  61F 49F 86F 50F 51F 82F 91F  52F  7F 32F
#> 5  73M 92M 55M 80M 11M  9M 45M  81M 35M  2M
#> 6  42F 23F  3F 79F 47F 10F 28F  57F 40F 31F
#> 7  65M 63M 88M 38M 27M 76M 67M  75M 83M 15M
#> 8  46F 44F 34F 60F 58F  6F 85F  89F 54F 98F
#> 9  37M 90M 68M  5M 93M 41M 72M  87M  8M 19M
#> 10 99F 18F 17F 97F 24F 12F 39F 100F 84F 36F

dataset %>% 
  mutate(across(X1:X10, ~ str_extract(., ".$")))
#>    X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
#> 1   M  M  M  M  M  M  M  M  M   M
#> 2   F  F  F  F  F  F  F  F  F   F
#> 3   M  M  M  M  M  M  M  M  M   M
#> 4   F  F  F  F  F  F  F  F  F   F
#> 5   M  M  M  M  M  M  M  M  M   M
#> 6   F  F  F  F  F  F  F  F  F   F
#> 7   M  M  M  M  M  M  M  M  M   M
#> 8   F  F  F  F  F  F  F  F  F   F
#> 9   M  M  M  M  M  M  M  M  M   M
#> 10  F  F  F  F  F  F  F  F  F   F
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: A base R version of this is `dataset[] <- lapply(dataset, function(x) substring(x, nchar(x)))` which does not require a regular expression or additional packages.